# Getting Address Book permission crashes app iOS

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, viewdidload

I'm working on an iOS 7.1 app on Xcode 5.1.1 (can't be upgraded currently), with ARC and without a StoryBoard, and when I call an empty method in the viewDidLoad method, the app crashes at the end of my custom method. Currently, I'm thinking that it's either my older version of Xcode, or the fact that I'm not using a  StoryBoard, but I've simplified the code as much as possible and still cannot find the error. if someone could point out what I'm doing wrong, that would be great, thanks!

The crash just says Thread 1: breakpoint 1.1, crashing when `[self.window makeKeyAndVisible]` calls `[viewController viewDidLoad]`.

ViewController.h

```
@interface XYZContactsTableViewController : UITableViewController

@end
```

ViewController.m:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self getAddressBook];
}

- (void)getAddressBook {

} // App crashes at line point exactly
```

AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    XYZContactsTableViewController *viewController = [[XYZContactsTableViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Edits: 
Also, calling pure C functions in the viewDidLoad method works, so the problem has something to do with the viewController object.

Comment: @matt Added crash info, and renamed the method, but the crash still occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The crash just says Thread 1: breakpoint 1.1

Aha. You are not crashing at all. You are just pausing at a breakpoint. If you don't want to pause, or if breakpoints confuse you, take the breakpoint away or turn breakpoints off. Breakpoints are great, but you clearly don't understand them, so turn them off for now (but do learn to use them eventually, as they are extremely cool!).

Comment: You're right, what a terrible mistake! Thanks, I had tried everything except looking for an accidental breakpoint.

Comment: When in doubt, use the breakpoints navigator. You can learn a lot there! :)

Comment: Here's the section of my book about breakpoints and debugging. I hope it helps you! http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch09.html#_the_xcode_debugger

Comment: Thanks, book looks great, will probably be referring to it a lot, heh.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use some already implemented component? :)
Check [KBContactsSelection](http://blog.sigmapoint.pl/kbcontactsselection-ios-address-book-ui-library/) which allows you to search and select multiple contacts and is easily customizable using elegant [Builder Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern).

[image: KBContactsSelection screen]